# Automating query mapping with multiple joins via Linq2Db

Tags: c#, join, mapping, linq2db

I've been using BLToolkit for a while, and lately I've been testing Linq2Db as the author recommends.

I've been able to recreate most of the automations I did for BLToolkit, but I'm struggling to create a standard structure to query for data with multiple table joins and a subset of columns. Actually, the current method we're using is quite manual, and I'm trying to get to something more automatic that enables us to use LINQ to service provided by the linq2db framework on our clients.

Let's get started with a simplified example.

```
Table HEADER
    Column ID
    Column Name

Table LINE
    Column ID
    Column Header_Id
    Column Element_Id

Table ELEMENT
    Column ID
    Column Name
```

Having those tables I succesfully generated POCO classes and made queries individually and filling associations with Linq2Db. Now what I pretend is to query something like this:

```
SELECT 
    H.ID AS Header_Id, 
    H.Name AS Header_Name,
    L.ID AS Line_Id
    E.ID AS Element_Id
    E.Name AS Element_Name
FROM HEADER H JOIN LINE L ON H.ID = L.Header_Id 
              JOIN ELEMENT E ON L.Element_Id = E.ID
```

Given that I've set up a class like this:

```
public class FullOrderData
{
    public int Header_Id { get; set; }
    public string Header_Name { get; set; }
    public int Line_Id { get; set; }
    public int Element_Id { get; set; }
    public string Element_Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have no problem Querying it like:

```
using(var db = new MyTestDb())
{
    var orderData = db.Query<FullOrderData>(selectQuery).ToList();
}
```

Now what I want to achieve and what I've tried so far:

**Step one: Automate the query**

I'd like to somehow "embed" the query into the class' metadata, something like:

*Option 1*

```
[JoinObjectQuery("SELECT ....")]
public class FullOrderData
{
     ....
}

public static class DataConnectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> QueryJoinObject<T>(this DataConnection db)
   {
        //search for JoinObjectQuery attribute and invoke db.Query<T>(joinObjectQueryAttribute.Query)
   }
}
```

*Option 2*

```
public interface IJoinObject
{
    string BaseQuery { get; }
}

public class FullOrderData : IJoinObject
{
    public string BaseQuery => "SELECT....";
}

public static class DataConnectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> QueryJoin<T>(this DataConnection db) where T : IJoinObject, new()
   {
        return db.Query<T>(New<T>.Instance().BaseQuery)
   }
}
```

So far so good....or not so, since the first option forces the developer to know where to invoke db.Query() and when to invoke db.QueryJoinObject() and the second forces to create an extra dummy interface and create a new instance each time (although a cache could be implemented)

**Step two: Linq to SQL over these objects**

This is where science fiction starts for me, since I have no clue on how to approach this.

Obviously, if I execute:

```
db.Query<FullOrderData>().Where(x => x.Header_Id == 1).ToList()
```

linq2sql executes the full select query and then applies the Where over the already mapped objects. That's a real performance pain which I can't afford.

So, I'm searching for a way that somehow adorning the class linq2db can generate the SQL corresponding to the linq sentences.

What are your thoughts about what I exposed on the first step? Any suggestions about what direction to choose with the second step?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should have set in the Database the correct foreign keys;
2. At initialization use this

   ```
      LinqToDB.Common.Configuration.Linq.AllowMultipleQuery = true;
   ```

   You need this when you will have like Foreign not one row, but multiple, like a list of results.For example One User can have one password, but multiple relations in the access table.   In your example you don't need this.
3. In the query from linq use LoadWith(x=>x.constraint), depends on how you name it...

Here is an Example for your problem:

```
var result = db.Line
.LoadWith(x=>x.HeaderForeignKey)
.LoadWith(x=>x.ElementForeignKey)
.Where(x => x.HeaderForeignKey.Header_Id == 1).ToList()
```

You will have now the list of Lines with Elements and Headers inside, and only the data that you need from DB without this performance pain.

PS: Hope that's not too late ))